# How to create a virtual type to grant that given struct has some field with annotation @xxxx?

Tags: annotations, d

I would like to create a virtual struct, I mean as Input Range.
You can create a new struct type and to be an input range. I know
that use duck typing :-)

In my case i would like to use duck typing if a stuct of any type
have an a given attribute. By exbample if at least one field as
@MyUDA

with this i could send any type of struct to a function

```
struct MyUDA {}

struct A {
  @MyUDA int a1;
  @MyUDA float a2;
}


strct B {
  @MyUDA string b;
}

A a;
B b;
foo( a );
foo( b );
```

I hope that is enough clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use a constraint with a helper function:

```
enum MyUDA; // instead of struct so @MyUDA works instead of @MyUDA()

struct A {
  @MyUDA int a1;
  @MyUDA float a2;
}


struct B {
  @MyUDA string b;
}

void main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    foo( a );
    foo( b );
}

// this looks for the uda on a member
template HasMyUDA(T) {
    static bool helper() {
        foreach(memberName; __traits(allMembers, T)) {
            foreach(attr; __traits(getAttributes, __traits(getMember, T, memberName)))
                static if(is(attr == MyUDA))
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    enum HasMyUDA = helper();
}

// test usage
void foo(T)(T t) if(HasMyUDA!T) {
    pragma(msg, T.stringof ~ " works here");
}
```

Once you're inside the function, you still have to look for the members and do something with them, but there you are and it will reject any struct statically that has no marked members.